# Shiny Error : Warning: Error in seq.int: 'to' must be a finite number

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny and I am not sure why I get an error.

I already have created a function that takes an input a variable "name" and then after some lines I simply end by print(plot 1) print(plot 2). Now I want to make this function reactive using shiny.

I have already in my R session environment run the dataframe & the function. Then I run the shiny app using this code but I get this error. Do you have any idea what could be the issue? :/

Warning: Error in seq.int: 'to' must be a finite number

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Change graph"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      "playlist", "Select a Playlist Name", playlist_names)
    ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1<-renderPlot({playlist_name_plots("input$playlist")})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: ... at least I would try `playlist_name_plots(input$playlist)` without quotes.

Comment: That was the issue, I removed the quotes and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what's in `playlist_names` passed as `choices =` , quoted from `?selectinput`:

> List of values to select from. If elements of the list are named, then that name — rather than the value — is displayed to the user. It's also possible to group related inputs by providing a named list whose elements are (either named or unnamed) lists, vectors, or factors. In this case, the outermost names will be used as the group labels (leveraging the  HTML tag) for the elements in the respective sublist. See the example section for a small demo of this feature.

Working example:

```
library(shiny)

playlist_names <- c("Playlist A","Playlist B","Playlist C")

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Change graph"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      "playlist", "Select a Playlist Name", playlist_names)
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1<-renderPlot({playlist_name_plots(input$playlist)})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but I forgot to mention that I had already assigned this to a variable- solid point though!!

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with that variable. Where do you assign it?

Comment: The issue was at the "" at the variable input, which was also corrected in your answer!! thanks a lot!